# Tableau: "Unknown function DATEPARSE called" after data source migration

Tags: tableau-api, tableau-desktop

Small question regarding Tableau and the DATEPARSE function please.

I used to have a CSV, nothing special, that has a column Mytimestamp.
The values of the column Mytimestamp would be just like those: Mytimestamp 1628670242328 1619671382146

`DATE(DATEPARSE ( "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", STR(DATEADD('second', (INT([Mytimestamp]/1000)), #1970-01-01#)) ))`

Again, this worked really great, no problem.
Now, we have couple of other data sources, and I just replaced the original data source, the CSV file, to those new datasource.

Unfortunately, all dashboard using this broke, with this issue.
"Unknown function DATEPARSE called".

May I ask how to fix this, and get the behavior I was having with the CSV please?
What would be an alternative to this DATEPARSE function which can help "convert" those timestamps into a human readable format.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct answer is to use `DATETIME`

```
DATE(DATEPARSE ( STR(DATEADD('second', (INT([Mytimestamp]/1000)), #1970-01-01#)) ))
```

Some data sources, such as CSV, supports DATEPARSE
But some others does not, and the `DATETIME` is the answer.

Comment: Thank you! DATETIME worked for me, although I don't see it mentioned in the code of your answer. This is the code I used in my calculated field: IF [date_field] >= DATETIME("2022-09-07") then "good" END